# Disposing kurento webrtc endpoints from java and javascript doesn't remove it from chrome webrtcinternals

Tags: webrtc, kurento

We are releasing the webrtc endpoints when user leaves the group call and same on the java script side (disposing the webrtc peer).

In the java logs I also get a callback for successful release of webrtc endpoints.

However, that webrtc peer is not getting removed when we monitor Chrome's webrtc internals. But, those peers don't show any traffic.

Is this an issue with Chrome's webrtc internals that it is not getting cleared from the list?

-Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue when releasing `RTCPeerConnection` resources. The standard does not specify when those resources must be freed, so they stay there until you reload the page. There's little we can do about that, sorry!

Unless of course we are doing something wrong ;-)